# UIImageView width in viewDidLayoutSubviews is 1000?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint

I have an `UIview` that on top of itself has an `UIImageView`. I want both to be rounded so I wrote these lines of code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        // make rounded profile image
        self.avatarPlaceholderView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.avatarPlaceholderView.layer.cornerRadius = self.avatarPlaceholderView.frame.width / 2.0
        self.avatarImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.avatarImageView.frame.width / 2.0
    }
```

On paper everything should work fine, but it isn't. While `UIView` becomes rounded, `UIImageView` isn't shown at all. Further investigation showed that `self.avatarPlaceholderView.frame.width` returns proper width, but `self.avatarImageView.frame.width` returns width of 1000. What is even more strange if I comment last 2 lines, `UIImageView` will be visible, so constraints are set properly.

I have no idea why this is happening.

**EDIT**

Storyboard screen shots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Show more info , constraints/hierarchy of views,etc..

Comment: It is much easier to subclass `UIImageView` and use `layoutSubviews`. Also, then you can just change the class in storyboard and you won't need more code.

Comment: Are you sure you are running your app with the correct size class? I see that you have `This Size Class` marked in your view. Wouldn't `All` make more sense there?

Comment: Changing it to all, has no effect. By the way, this size class is default value. Also i probably could find another way to do this, but i am really curious why this doesn't work, and by all means it should

Comment: @MegaManX I found an Xcode 8 workaround that I have added to my answer in case you're still struggling with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact same thing happened to me as well. Had a `UIImageView` that was being converted to a circle post `awakeFromNib` via:

```
self.iv.layer.masksToBounds = true;
self.iv.layer.cornerRadius = self.iv.frame.width/2;
```

Found the root cause and you're not going to like it - **XCode 8** (surprise surprise).

With absolutely no changes made the `.xib` that contained my imageview the corner radius modification worked fine. However, as soon as I opened this `.xib` file in XCode 8 (without changing anything), the image view circle modification no longer worked. This was because, as you noticed, the imageview's width was being detected as 1000 instead of the constant width constraint I had set to (32).

As you probably know xcode changes `.xib` entries almost every time you open one, even if no modifications are performed. A lot of these are trivial IDE version tags but occasionally as with changes between major IDE version they alter non-trivial properties of the `.xib` for "compatibility" purposes.

---

**Workaroud:** until Apple fixes this...

1. Open your `.xib` file and perform any changes you need.
2. Open the file inspector tab on the right hand side of Xcode
3. Under the **Interface Builder Document** section, select "Opens in Xcode 7.x"
4. This will prompt you to save and close the `.xib`. Do so and *do not open the file again without performing these steps after each change*
5. Run your app again. 1000 width & height issue fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to run `self.avatarPlaceholderView.layoutIfNeeded()` whenever you change it´s `frame/bounds` properties and it will layout to the new `frame/bounds`.

Comment: the thing is i am not changing frame or bounds, i just run the app, these are constraints from storyboard.

Comment: Add it anyway in the beginning after `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, try that and see what happens.

Comment: doing it like that, it shows correct value, but i am curious why shouldn't it work even without that line. All views should have correct frames in super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Comment: @MegaManX, `layoutIfNeeded` forces the receiver to layout its subviews immediately if required and apparently it´s needed in your situation since you added and updated the `layer` for your `avatarPlaceholderView`.

Comment: still aren't you curious why it works for plain view, and not for uiimageview? I am changing layer property also on uiview, and it doesn't need layoutIfNeeded

Comment: When you set autolayout to a property and change it´s values you need to add `layoutIfNeeded`so your `uiimageview`changes it values somehow and the `uiview` doesn't. I have tried this myself and you also need to `layoutIfNeeded` an `uiview` sometimes. This is the answer I can give you, hopefully it´s working for you now. Good luck!